# Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms: Excel export data rows are collapsed and some data is missing

Tags: c#, excel, reporting

I am using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms to generate an Excel (old format xls, not xlsx) spreadsheet from various reports. However for some of the reports, I'm getting all the data rows coming out as collapsed/hidden:

[image]

How can I force the data rows of the report to actually appear and not collapse/hide themselves?

edit: also, sometimes certain data rows (such as names of people in a particular role) are being omitted from the Excel export even though they export properly as PDF, HTML, or Word formats.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a Height="0.25" attribute on the rows in the report definition fixed this.